# How to (idiomatically in R) create a data.frame from values with column and row indexes?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame l, where each row contains three cells: 'x', 'y', 'value'. I need to create a new data.frame with the values in it by the indexes 'x' and 'y'. My naive solution is this:

```
out = data.frame()
for(i in 1:nrow(l)) {
    row <- l[i,]
    out[row[['x']], row[['y']]] <- row['value']
}
```

Is there an idiomatic way, how to do this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about:

```
tapply(l$value,list(l$x,l$y),mean)
```

Another option:

```
out = array(NA,dim=c(max(l$x),max(l$y)))
out[cbind(l$x,l$y)]=l$value
```

Comment: It works. Also with identity(x) instead of mean(x, ...). Thanks.